# How to compare any files in ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, compare

Do somebody know any gems to compare any txt or doc or pdf files? I need to compare and show differences like git

[git comparison example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZFIG.png)

Comment: you can simply do git diff

Comment: or just `\`diff "#{file1}" "#{file2}"\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice gem called [diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy) (it uses `diff` behind the scenes)
just add it to your application:

```
gem "diffy"
```

and then you can simply use it to compare strings:

```
diff = Diffy::Diff.new(s1, s2)
puts diff
```

or files:

```
diff = Diffy::Diff.new(file1_path, file2_path, source: "files")
puts diff
```

It has nice options such as HTML output as well as providing basic CSS styles.

Please see the [documentation](https://github.com/samg/diffy).

Answer (score 2):

You can compare text files by doing this:-

```
f1 = IO.readlines("text_file1.txt").map(&:chomp)
f2 = IO.readlines("text_file1.txt").map(&:chomp)

File.open("diff.txt","w"){ |f| f.write((f1-f2).join("\n")) }
```